# Recursive Array Map with Laravel Collection map() Helper

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have a collection of data.

```
$array = [

    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'some1',
        'type' => 'type1',
        'color' => 'color1',
        'quantity' => 1
    ],

    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'some1',
        'type' => 'type1',
        'color' => 'color1',
        'quantity' => 1
    ],

    [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'some1',
        'type' => 'type1',
        'color' => 'color2',
        'quantity' => 1
    ],

    [
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'some2',
        'type' => 'color1',
        'color' => 'type1',
        'quantity' => 1
    ],

     ......
];
```

that have different **name, type, and color**.

I want to group the data by **name, type, and color** and the result is array data with summary of the same group data.

First, I use this way :

```
function groupedData($array)
{

    $collection = [];

    collect($array)->groupBy('name')->map(

        function ($item) use (&$collection) { 

            return $item->groupBy('type')->map(

                function ($item) use (&$collection) { 

                    return $item->groupBy('color')->map(

                        function ($item) use (&$collection) {

                            $quantity = $item->sum('quantity');
                            $collection[] = collect($item[0])->merge(compact('quantity'));
                        }
                    );
                }
            ); 
        }
    );

    return $collection;
}
```

I expect the output should be like this :

```
$grouped = [

    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'some1',
        'type' => 'type1',
        'color' => 'color1',
        'quantity' => 2
    ],

    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'some1',
        'type' => 'type1',
        'color' => 'color2',
        'quantity' => 1
    ],

    [
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'some2',
        'type' => 'type1',
        'color' => 'color1',
        'quantity' => 2
    ],

    [
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'some2',
        'type' => 'type2',
        'color' => 'color1',
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
];
```

where quantity represent of the number of group items.

But, I the problem is when the required is changed. Just in case :
when user want add other category for grouping, example :
user want to group by **name, type, color and size** maybe.

**Question** : How to make a function that can make it more simple and flexible, so doesn't need to change the code when the require changes?

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your code has two `return` statements, and it's hard to follow. Can you show some sample output data?

Comment: Thanks @JosephSilber

Sorry, I have updated the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for it sorting, not grouping.

Here's an easy way to do it:

```php
function sort($array, $keys) {
    return collect($array)->sortBy(function ($item) use ($keys) {
        return array_reduce($keys, function ($carry, $key) use ($item) {
            return $carry + $item[$key];
        }, '');
    })->all();
}
```

Here's a short explanation:

1. We're using the collection's [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sortby) method, which let's us use a callback function that'll return a string to determine the sort order.
2. We're using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) on the keys to build a single string of all the values in the keys we want to sort by.
3. Laravel's collection object will use that resulting string to order the collection by.
4. Finally, we call the [`all`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-all) method to get the underlying array from the collection. If you want to actually return a collection, you can remove that last `all` call.